Electrodynamics: tube’s contract and expansion

Figure is a doughnut-shaped shrinking and expanding material. I want to know if the doughnut-shaped material contracts or expands when the current is flowing clockwise here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
